# Using `which` with list components of length larger than 1

Tags: r, list

I have a list similar to the following:

```
> x <- list(
    j = "first",
    k = "second",
    l = "third",
    m = c("first", "second"),
    n = c("first", "second", "third"),
    o = c("first", "third"),
    p = c("second", "third"),
    q = "first",
    r = "third")
```

I need to create index of the string components based on their value. I can easily do this with `which` for components containing elements of single strings:

```
> which(x == "third")
l r
3 9
```

Or even for multiple components that contain elements of single strings:

```
> which(x == "first" | x == "second" | x == "third")
j k l q r
1 2 3 8 9
```

The returned value shows me the number of the components in the list and its name. However, sometimes I would need to obtain an index of components that contain character vectors that have more than one element such as `m` (`c("first", "second")`) or `n` (`c("first", "second", "third")`). That is, the length of the character vector in the components would be larger than 1. I thought the following would work:

```
which(x == c("first", "second"))
```

I was wrong, the output was:

```
j k
1 2
Warning message:
In x == c("first", "second") :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

It is the same when I try with more than one condition:

```
> which(x == "first" | x == c("first", "second"))
j k q
1 2 8
Warning message:
In x == c("first", "second") :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

The desired output from `which(x == c("first", "second"))` is:

```
m
4
```

The desired output from `which(x == "first" | x == c("first", "second"))` is:

```
j m q
1 4 8
```

How this could be done? Not necessary to use `which`, thou...

Comment: Use `%in%` instead of `==` if you want compare against a set of values. P.S. you can't downgrade a post on SO, maybe downvote.

Comment: It is not a duplicate! This question is about doing this element-wise in a list....

Comment: @panman use sapply to apply a function (like `function(v) 'first' %in% v`) element-wise in a list. At the end, it should look like: `which(sapply(x, function(v) 'first' %in% v))`.

Comment: What is your desired output for `which(x == c("first", "second"))`?

Comment: @ David Arenburg: Not really what I want. With `which(x %in% c("first", "second"))` it returns 1, 2, and 8 which is quite different than what I am looking for. Yes, downvote, not downgrade. I understand you find my question a duplicate, can you please provide a link?

Comment: Can you explain what is your desired output for `which(x == c("first", "second"))` then? You only showed what you don't want to achieve rather what you want to achieve.

Comment: For example this : `grep("first, second", lapply(x, toString))`  or maybe this
`which("first, second" == lapply(x, toString))`?

Comment: @ David Arenburg: `which("first, second" == lapply(x, toString))` works and returns `m` (4). But what about the case `which(x == "first" | x == c("first", "second"))` where I need `j` and `m`? (see the updated quastion)

Comment: You could probably do something like ```which(sapply(lapply(x, toString), `%in%`, c("first", "first, second")))```. What about `q` btw, why isn't it included in your desired output? It's the same as `j`, no?

Comment: @ David Arenburg: returns an error `Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "which(sapply(lapply(x, toString), %in%"`. You are right about `q`, was my mistake, sorry about this. I edited the question, now is correct.

Comment: Don't know. Works perfectly fine for me with your data set. See Alexis answer, it's probably better.

Comment: @ David Arenburg: Will try it later again. Thank you very much for your efforts David.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `"list" == "character"` the "list" is converted to "character" as `as.character(x)` which, I assume, is unwanted. You could use `match` to compare between "list"s corresponding elements:

```
ff = function(x, table) which(setNames(table %in% x, names(table)))
ff(list("third"), x)
#l r 
#3 9 
ff(list("first", "second", "third"), x) # your "|"
#j k l q r 
#1 2 3 8 9 
ff(list(c("first", "second")), x)
#m 
#4 
ff(list("first", c("first", "second")), x) # your "|"
#j m q 
#1 4 8
```

Comment: That's a nice approach as always. Wouldn't have to convert this to a `list`.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what needed. Works flawlessly, I tried it with other combinations and adding even more elements I would like to include. Works like charm. Thank you very much Alexis!